# "Secure Connection Failed" only when using VPN

Tags: networking, firefox, vpn, ssl, https

When I try to log into a certain website with HTTPS, I get a "Secure Connection Failed" error from Firefox, and a similar error when I try other browsers.

Interestingly, this only happens when I am connected to a VPN. When I disconnect from the VPN, it works fine.

This does not affect other pages of the same website, such as the log-in page; it only happens when I submit the form to log in. It also does not affect other websites that use HTTPS (I can't confirm that it's only one, just not all).

What is a possible explanation? Is there something wrong with the VPN server, the website, or my computer?

Comment: Apparently, something (read, the VPN server) is tampering with your traffic on its way to you.

Comment: can also be caused by MTU issues.  VPNs typically reduce MTU due to VPN tunnel framing overhead.  Some software / stacks don't respond well to this at all.  We've seen in the past problems with TLS when there's a reduced MTU in the path between client and server.  You could try using ping to discover the MTU, and adjust MTU on your adapter (that is used for the VPN) to fall within.

Answer (score 1):

Check the details on the certificate that the browser is stating is bad.  If the certificate comes from your company's domain, you are receiving an SSL certificate from the VPN concentrator and then making the connection on your behalf via a web proxy.  This is typically done in order to do Deep Packet Inspection of SSL based traffic.  If you make the connection to the proxy and then they make the connection to the https site for you, the proxy can decrypt the transmission because they have control of the necessary keys to view into the traffic which would otherwise be encrypted if you made a direct connection to the server from your browser.